# Load array to Doctrine_Collection

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

The question is about doctrine 1.2 and Symfony 1.4

In short: I am running simple SQL query and fetching results into array with PDO. After it, I create Doctrine_Collection of the same table I've fetched data from and call to synchronizeFromArray to load the data into collection.

Everything is fine - collection is created and all the data up there beside of my primary key which happens to be boolean false instead of real value.

Here is example of the code:

```
// Fetch single object from DB
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments LIMIT 1";
$p = $connection->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($p); // I see that all the data including `id` is ok

$c = new Doctrine_Collection('Payment', 'id');
$c->synchronizeFromArray($p);

var_dump($c->toArray()); // All the data is ok but `id` == false
```

I tried to use Doctrine_Collection::fromArray instead of synchronizeFromArray but it give same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. During `Doctrine_Collection::fromArray` (`synchronizeFromArray` too) record primary keys (`DoctrineRecord::_id` array) won't get updated.
2. `DoctrineRecord::toArray()` will overwrite all primary key column values with result of `DoctrineRecord::getIncremented()` which because of point 1. is empty.

One way to deal with this is to modify your `$p` array before you perform `fromArray()`.
Inside your array you should **change your primary key name to `_identifier`**.

In your case simplest solution would be to modify your SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` as `_identifier`, * FROM payments LIMIT 1";
```

This way following code from Doctrine_Record::fromArray():

```
if ($key == '_identifier') {
    $refresh = true;
    $this->assignIdentifier($value);
    continue;
}
```

will assign proper `_id` array to your records.